# Repeating a airflow DAG with different date parameters for data migrations

Tags: python-3.x, airflow

For the data migrations ,I have created a DAG which ultimately inserts data to a migration table after all the tasks with required logic.

DAG has a sql which is something similar to the below which initially extracts the data and feeds to other tasks:

```
sql=" select col_names from tables where created_on >=date1 and created_on <=date2"
```

For each DAG run Iam manually changing date1 and date2 in above sql and initiating data migrations(as data chunk is heavy,as of now date range length is 1 week).

I just want to automate this date changing process ex.if i give date intervals ,after the first DAG is run,the second run is initiated and so on until the end date interval.

I have researched so far,one solution I got was dynamic DAGS in airflow.But the problem is it creates multiple DAG file instances and its also very difficult to debug and maintain .

Is there a way to repeat a DAG with changing date parameter so that I no longer have to keep changing dates manually.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue! Backfilling in Airflow doesn't seem to make any sense if you don't have the DAG interval start and end as input parameters. If you want to do data migration, you'll probably need to store your last migration time in a file to read. However, this goes against some of the properties an Airflow DAG/task should have (idempotence).

My solution was to add two tasks to my DAG before the start of my "main" tasks. I have two operators (you can possibly make it one) which gets the start and end times of the current DAG run. The "start" and "end" names are sort of misleading because the "start" is actually the start of the previous run and "end" the start of the current run.

I can't reveal the custom operator I wrote but you can do this in a single Python operator:

```py
from croniter import croniter

def get_interval_start_end(**kwargs):

    dag = kwargs['dag']
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    dag_execution = ti.execution_date # current DAG scheduled start
    dag_interval = dag._scheduled_interval # note the preceding underscore
    cron_iter = croniter(dag_interval, dag_execution)
    dag_prev_execution = cron_iter.get_prev()
    return (dag_execution, dag_prev_execution)

# dag

task = PythonOperator(task_id='blabla',
    python_callable=get_interval_start_end,
    provide_context=True)

# other tasks
```

Then pull these values from `xcom` in your next task.

There is also a way to get the "last_run" of the DAG using `dag.get_last_dagrun()` instead. However, it doesn't return the previous scheduled run but the previous actual run. If you have already run your DAG for a "future" time, your "last dag run" will be after your current execution! Then again, I might not have tested with the right settings, so you can try that out first.

Comment: Hi, In my case the intervals to be like,if i want to migrate Jan 2018 data, data is fetched in week chunks, intervals would be  2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07,2018-01-02 to 2018-01-08 ,2018-01-09 to 2018-01-15 and so on.. How can i generate this dynamically and keep running DAG until end date is encountered

Comment: @Chandan Are the chunks overlapping or mutually exclusive? If they are overlapping like 2018/01/01 - 2018/01/07, 2018/01/02 - 2018/01/08, ..., you can still set the scheduled interval to daily, but use a different offset (one week) for your start DAG time. That is, get the start time of the current run and minus timedelta of 7 days. If they are separate, you can just change your scheduled interval to run weekly and use the same code.

Comment: The chunks/intervals  to be fetched are like :  2018-01-01 to 2018-01-07,2018-01-08 to 2018-01-15,2018-01-16 to 2018-01-23 and so on and intervals are mutually exclusive,how can I generate this and make DAG run till last interval.A code snippet if you can share will be helpful.

Comment: @Chandan The code snippet is already in the answer. You just need to add your own DAG definition and a task that pulls the xcom variable out to check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar req and here is how I accessed the dates which later can be used in SQLs for backfill.

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators import BashOperator, PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# Following are defaults which can be overridden later on
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2020, 8, 1),
    'end_date': datetime(2020, 8, 3),
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG('helloWorld_v1', default_args=default_args, catchup=True, schedule_interval='0 1 * * *')

def print_dag_run_date(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)
    execution_date = kwargs['ds']
    prev_execution_date = kwargs['prev_ds']
    return (execution_date, prev_execution_date)


# t1, t2 are examples of tasks created using operators

bash = BashOperator(
    task_id='bash',
    depends_on_past=True,
    bash_command='echo "Hello World from Task 1"',
    dag=dag)

py = PythonOperator(
    task_id='py',
    depends_on_past=True,
    python_callable=print_dag_run_date,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)


py.set_upstream(bash)
```